# Hashing from 128 bit to 16/18 bit in C?

Tags: hash, c

We have to convert a 128 bit unique number to a 16/18 bit unique number. Are there any hashing techniques for this in C, or any other possible ways to do that?

Comment: You are asking about a specific programming problem (i.e. code or library which does this for you) which is off-topic here. If you would ask about an algorithm it would be on-topic.

Comment: I want to know are there any algorithm for that hashing.

Comment: You could use any cryptographic hash like md5, sha1, ... and simply strip all the bytes you don't want. Of course there are possible collisions since you are reducing from 128 bit to 16/18 bit. And there are also other (non-cryptographic) hashes available depending on what you need but these are not a topic for information security. There are differences in speed, resistance against reverting etc. The best way depends on your exact use case which you did not include in your question.

Comment: This question is rather off topic here (an would be almost anywhere on the stack exchange network because you ask for off-site references). Fortunately, you could find interesting hints on this rather old [question](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/49550/which-hashing-algorithm-is-best-for-uniqueness-and-speed) on [Software Engeneering](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/). Or you could google for hash function or hash library...

Comment: You are asking to convert a 128 bit **unique** number to a 16/18 bit **unique** number. In the general setting, this is not possible due to the [pigeonhole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle) (there are many more 128-bit numbers than are 16/18-bit numbers).